# return [Object Object] in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the shared service to pass data between unrelated components. As i need to pass data from 2 different tables i have created 2 shared services. The first one works and return me the data i need but the second return me an [Object Object].

and here is my second shared service code :
**Shared2.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RepoService } from './repo.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Shared2Service {

  constructor(private service: RepoService) { }
  public data;
  setData(data){
   this.data = data;
 }
 
 getData(){
   let temp = this.data;
   this.clearData();
   return temp;
 }
 
 clearData(){
   this.data = undefined;
 }
}
```

**Sender.ts** :

```
constructor(private service:DealsService, private router : Router, private shared: SharedService, private service1 : RepoService, private shared2 : Shared2Service) {

 method2(data) {
    this.shared2.setData(data);
    console.log('deals data', data);
  }
  method(data){
     this.service1.sendGETRequestWithParameters(data.data.DEALID).subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data;
      console.log('repo data' , data );
      this.shared.setData(data);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/Repo'); 
    });
  }
  makeCellClicked(data) {
   this.method(data);
   this.method2(data);
  }
```

**Receiver.ts :**

```
export class RepoComponent implements OnInit {
  data = this.shared.getData(); 
  datas = this.shared2.getData();
  
  constructor( private router: Router, private shared: SharedService, private service:RepoService, private shared2 : Shared2Service ) {
    if(this.data){
      console.log('Table Repo data', this.data);
    }
    if(this.datas){
      console.log('Table Deals data' + this.datas);
    }
```

Thank you and have a great day !

Comment: The `+` concatenates string types. Try comma: `console.log('Table Deals data', this.datas);`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelD sorry for this stupid post ^^